# Why cannot I view input text in the Firefox browser?

Tags: css, firefox

When I go to `http://128.199.58.229/landingpage/` in Chrome and Safari I can read the placeholder text and see the text I input.

In Firefox I don't see any input text.

When I change the padding..

```
.form-control {
color: #A1A1A1;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 0;
}
```

I can see the text.. but of course the padding is terrible now. Any fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Voting to close as this problem cannot be re-created and the problem that was in the link provided has been fixed. You have your answer though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `.form-control` to `box-sizing: content-box` and provide a smaller padding value.

Like this:

```
.form-control {
    color: #A1A1A1;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Currently, the `box-sizing: border-box` property is combining the padding with the height and creating unexpected results in Firefox.

`box-sizing` is explained nicely [over here on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disturbing padding change the height to 54px

```
.form-control {
color: #A1A1A1;
font-size: 16px;
height: 54px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was height,Your padding is too much

**CSS**

```
.form-control
{
height:100%;
padding: 10px;
}
```